# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'product_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to do a multidimensional array in jQuery.

```
var parent = $(this).parents(".product:first").find(".decking_var_content > li");
var product_id = $(this).parents('.product:first').find( '.variations_form').find('input[name=product_id]').val();
var myarray = [];

parent.each(function() {
    var var_id = $(this).find("span").attr("data-id");
    var quantity = $(this).find(".decking_var_child_ul").find("input[name=quantity]").val();

    if (var_id) {   
        myarray[var_id]['product_id'] = product_id; //error points here
        myarray[var_id]['quantity'] = quantity;
        myarray[var_id]['variation_id'] = var_id;
    } 
    else {
        myarray[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity;
    }
});
```

The error points at this `myarray[var_id]['product_id'] = product_id;`  .
I have alerted `product_id` so i know it holds a value.

How do I solve this?

Comment: but i set the variable `myarray` as an array?  `var myarray =[];`

Comment: You set `myarray` as an array, but `myarray[var_id]` is undefined. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialise `myarray[var_id]` by creating an object in there before setting its properties:

```
if (var_id) {  
    myarray[var_id] = {}; 
    myarray[var_id]['product_id'] = product_id;
    myarray[var_id]['quantity'] = quantity;
    myarray[var_id]['variation_id'] = var_id;
} 
else {
    myarray[product_id] = {};
    myarray[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity;
}
```

Note that you can make this code more succinct, like this:

```
if (var_id) {  
    myarray[var_id] = {
        'product_id': product_id,
        'quantity': quantity,
        'variation_id': var_id
    }; 
} 
else {
    myarray[product_id] = {
        'quantity': quantity
    };
}
```

Comment: when i check the header response in google chrome `product_array[]: ` is shown 50 times before it actually shows the array values.  It only loops twice, why does it show several blank  `product_array[]: ` ?

Comment: That would depend on the number of iterations in your `parent.each(fn)` loop

Comment: the number of iterations is only two?

Comment: I would start a new question about that, with a working example if you can.

Answer (score 2):

assign the **{}** ,before inserting value

```
myarray[var_id]={};
myarray[var_id]['product_id'] = product_id; //error points here
myarray[var_id]['quantity'] = quantity;
myarray[var_id]['variation_id'] = var_id;
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4pounzvg/1/)**